# Why does the 'a' parameter of my "quicksort" function which accepts list of values from the user is throwing error: "NameError"?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm new to Python and computer programming in general, So after going through basic tutorials online I implemented Quick sort. I'm getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quicksort.py", line 1, in <module>
    def quicksort(a, left = 0, right = len(a)):
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Complete code::

```
def quicksort(a, left = 0, right = len(a)):
    if(left<right):
        pivotindx = quick(a, left, right)
        quicksort(a, left, pivotindx-1)
        quicksort(a,pivotindx+1,right)
    return a




def quick(arr, start = 0, end = len(a)):
    pivot = arr[start]
    swpindx = start
    i = start + 1
    while(i < end):
        if(pivot > arr[i]):
            swpindx+=1
            arr[swpindx] , arr[i] = arr[i] , arr[swpindx]
        i+=1    

    arr[start] , arr[swpindx] = arr[swpindx] , arr[start]  
    return swpindx      


arr = []
size = int(input('enter size of array:'))
for i in range(size):
    x = int(input(f'enter value {i}:'))
    arr.append(x)
size = len(arr)    
result = quicksort(arr, 0, size) 
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify the `len(a)` when declaring the function.

In python when you specify `=` when declaring the function it is default parameter.
So it is used when you don't provide it when calling the function.

```
In [36]: def hello(name, surename="James"): 
    ...:     print(name, surename) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                      

In [37]: hello("Thomas")                                                                                                                      
Thomas James

In [38]: hello("Thomas","Shelby")                                                                                                             
Thomas Shelby
```

Comment: I refactored it, but it is still throwing the same error.   
 Here is the refactored code :: https://shrib.com/#BlackEyedBulbul8V9W65V

Comment: Probably have not refreshed code, I run your code and no error.